# Reading XML with Pandas swaps xlink:label and element text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to the Pandas library and ran into the following issue when trying to read a XMl file.

XML file I tried to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<link:linkbase>
<link:label xml:lang="en-US" xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="us-gaap_TradeNamesMember_lbl" xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label">Trade Names [Member]</link:label>
</link:linkbase>
```

code to parse the XML to a DataFrame:

```
label_df = pd.read_xml(open(filing_lab), xpath="//*[local-name() = 'label']", )
```

This is the DataFrame that´s been created:

```
    lang    type        label                   role
0   en-US   resource    Trade Names [Member]    http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label
```

As you can see the value of the "xlink:label" attribute of the XML element "label" has not been added to the DataFrame. Instead the element´s text has been added as "label" column. How can I make sure both the value of xlink:label and the element´s text get added to the DataFrame?

Comment: Please validate your XML snipped, namespace definiton is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this valid version of your xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<linkbase>
    <label xml:lang="en-US" type="resource" label="us-gaap_TradeNamesMember_lbl" role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label">Trade Names [Member]</label>
</linkbase>
```

Here is one way to do it

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_xml("file.xml", attrs_only=True),
        pd.read_xml("file.xml", attrs_only=False).rename(columns={"label": "text"})[
            "text"
        ],
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
    lang      type                         label  \
0  en-US  resource  us-gaap_TradeNamesMember_lbl   

                                  role                  text  
0  http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/label  Trade Names [Member]
```

Comment: This is what I´ve been looking for. Thanks a lot!